Can we access a Samba File Share on an EC2 instance from a local machine over public internet?
I have a samba file share that I have set up on my Ubuntu EC2 instance (Instance A). I am able to access this file share from another Windows Server EC2 instance (Instance B) through both the private IP and public ip of Instance A
I want to be able to access the file share via my local laptop over public internet. I know its not a great idea with security concerns in mind, but its just a test project of mine, I might probably use EFS or so for a production version. Anyways, I have been trying to set this up the entire day and it seems there is no way to get it working.
I tried different settings and configs in the samba.conf but none of them work. I have the 445 port opened only to my IP in the Instance A security group.
Has anyone done something similar? I am curious to know if its at all possible, without a VPN, etc ?

This is a very bad idea - but as you mention AWS, have you ensured the AWS firewall lets the traffic through?   Would setting up a VPN be an option for your use case?  (Much more secure, no hassles with ports)

Configure OpenVPN - a Samba server shouldn't be directly accessible from WAN

In theory, yes. SMB is just a regular TCP-based protocol that runs over port 445 (or the legacy port 139). If you can connect to the server over TCP/445 you can use SMB – provided that the latency isn't too high (otherwise it might be an unpleasant experience).
In practice, probably not. Many residential ISPs block port 445 in all directions, because of the sheer amount of security issues and vulnerabilities associated with it in the past – they want to prevent their customers' infected machines from contacting and infecting other machines. (And still today, if weak admin passwords are used, but there used to be so many exploits that would bypass that outright – most of them in Windows' SMBv1-specific code, hence the saying that "SMBv1 is insecure".)
So if you get connection timeouts, test with tcpdump to see whether the server receives port-445 packets at all. (tcpdump -n -i eth0 'port 445' or tshark -n -i eth0 -f 'port 445' is a good start.)
(Many corporate networks block port 445 for a different reason: leakage of NTLM domain credentials. While it's possible to enforce Kerberos client-side these days, previously NTLM was always-on, and it used to be easy to trick someone's corporate workstation into connecting to a malicious SMB server that would then relay the NTLM handshake to a corp server and do all kinds of bad things.)
Since many SMB clients do not let you change the port number being used, it means you're likely to be unable to connect to any SMB server across the Internet, if your ISP has such a block.
(Also, while Samba is of course not vulnerable to Windows-specific exploits, there is still the issue of SMB not being very resistant against snooping. You'd have to enforce SMBv3 encryption and use Kerberos authentication for it to actually be secure – NTLM over Internet remains a bad idea even if SMB encryption is on... although such a combination is still certainly better than nothing; both SMBv2 or SMBv1 are straight out due to their lack of encryption.)
